# properly discontinuous action in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, group-actions

Let be  $(X,d)$ a metric space, $G$ a group acting on $X$. The action is properly discontinuous if and only if for all $x \in X$ exists $k>0$ such that $ \{g \in G | d(x,gx) < k\} = \{e\}$.

$G$ is acting by isometries and properly discontinuous action is an action such that for all $x \in X$ exists a neighborhood U of $x$ such that, if $g \neq e$, $gU \cap U$ = empty. $ \\ $ $ \ \ $

I learning on my own and I found this observation and I can not prove it. I can not see why proper discontinuous action is equivalent to that in a metric space.

Comment: What's your definition of a properly discontinuous action?

Comment: For all $x \in X$ exists a neighborhood U of $x$ such that, if $g \neq e$,  $g U \cap U $ = empty

Comment: Are you assuming $G$ acts by isometries?  If you just assume it acts by homeomorphisms I don't think this is true, though I don't know a counterexample off the top of my head.

Comment: Yes, I assuming $G$ is acting by isometries.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: ($\rightarrow$) Take $x \in X$, X is a metric space so exists $r>0$ such that $B_r (x)$ = $U$ and we have $gU \in X$. Like the action is properly discontinuous we hace $gU \cap U$=empty (with $g \neq e$), so exists $k>0$ such that $d(gB_r(x) \cap B_r(x) ) < r $... and I have nothing after this.

Comment: you have some problems here: first you you do have some $r>0$ with $B_r(x)\subseteq U$ but not necessarily equal to $U$ and $gU$ is a subset of $X$ it is not in $X$. And i didn't quit get what you are trying to do. If you would like people to answer, you should edit your question, add the definitions and explain what you tried up until now.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ acts properly discontinuously and let $x\in X$.  Let $U$ be a neigborhood of $x$ such that $gU\cap U=\emptyset$ for all $g\neq e$.  Let $k>0$ be such that $U$ contains the ball of radius $k$ around $x$.  Then if $g\neq e$, $gx\in gU$ so $gx\not\in U$.  In particular, $d(x,gx)\geq k$.  This shows $k$ satisfies your condition.

Conversely, suppose the action of $G$ satisfies your condition and let $x\in X$.  Choose $k>0$ such that $\{g\in G:d(x,gx)<k\}=\{e\}$ and let $U$ be the ball of radius $k/2$ around $x$.  Since $G$ acts by isometries, $gU$ is the ball of radius $k/2$ around $gx$ for each $g\in G$.  If $g\neq e$, then if $y\in U$, $d(gx,y)\geq d(gx,x)-d(y,x)>k-k/2=k/2$.  Thus $y\not\in gU$.  Since $y\in U$ was arbitrary, $gU\cap U=\emptyset$.  Thus the action is properly discontinuous.